# how to limit access when one or more data on array have duplicate

Tags: php

i'm sorry if my english not good.

I have a problem in my code. how I can stop access when in my array have duplicate. I mean, when one or more data in array have duplicate, user must repeat input from first page. and when array have not duplicate, user can access next page.

this is my code I have try.

```
$no_id=array('100100','100200','100300','100200','100200','100100');
$array = array();
foreach ($no_id as $key => $value)
{
   if(isset($array[$value]))
   {
      $array[$value] += 1;
   } else
   {
      $array[$value] = 1;
   }
}
foreach ($array as $alert => $n)
{
   if($n >= 2)
   {
      header('location:../../home');
   } else
   {
      header('location:../../questionnair');
   }
}
```

but when found the duplicate data (in array 100100 have two data and 100200 three data), the system still bring user to access questionnair page, not home.

thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you maybe provide an expected output, as I don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: my expected output is when duplicate found in array, user must repeat access on first page. and when the duplicate not found in array, user can access to next page. I'm sorry, coz my english is not good.. so I can't explain it well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's simplier to use `array_unique` function, which will remove all duplicated values.
After that you can make checks, if nothing was changed, then there is no duplicated items.

Like this:

```
$no_id=array('100100','100200','100300','100200','100200','100100');
$no_id_unique = array_unique($no_id);

if(count($no_id)===count($no_id_unique)){
    header('location:../../questionnair');
}else{
    header('location:../../home');
}
exit();
```

Next thing that you using `../` in path which means `go to parent directory`.
I don't know your environment, but must likely it's a bad idea.

According to [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) it's better to specify full url of page where user must be forwarded:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/home/");
```

Also, please be aware, that you need to prevent all others output from a script, especcially before the `header()` call. Read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: thank you @krylov123 .. I'm still new to programming, so I do not understand the rules.. I got new knowledge from you, now my system still runs through localhost, so I think if using hosting is not a problem if I used " ../ ". thank you for helping and ifnormation

Answer (score 3):

I think the main problem is that you should always use `exit()` after using `header()` with location, otherwise the page will continue to execute.

This would still cause a problem though if the first value was a unique value as the first loop would always `exit;`.

You could fix this (only ever call `header()` if the value is > 2, then the default of all are unique is after the loop), but an alternative is to use `array_count_values()` which counts how many each value exists in the list and then use `max()` to find the most occurring one, then test against that...

```
$no_id=array('100100','100200','100300','100200','100200','100100');

$n = max(array_count_values($no_id));
if($n >= 2)
{
    header('location:../../home');
    exit;
} else
{
    header('location:../../questionnair');
    exit;
}
```

**Update:**

An alternative and slightly quicker version would be to use your original first loop, but as soon as it detects the value is already set, then it can stop working and just return then...

```
$no_id=array('100100','100200','100300','100200','100200','100100');
$array = array();
foreach ($no_id as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset($array[$value]))
    {
        header('location:../../home');
        exit;
    } else
    {
        $array[$value] = 1;
    }
}
header('location:../../questionnair');
exit;
```

Comment: your explanation makes me understand. and I think my mistake is not thinking about using max() and array_count_values() .. thank you for helping.

Comment: I've added another version which may also be useful.

Comment: thank you @nigel.. i think iseet can only be used when using $ _POST and $ _GET ... thanks, I got to know other functions of the code.

Comment: @AquaRius it looks like you question is answered by NigelRen?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check if the array does have dupliate, you can use `array_unique` and compare the new array with the old array. If the arrays are not the same, it means there are duplicates.

With code:

```
$no_id = array('100100','100200','100300','100200','100200','100100');
$new_array = array_unique($no_id);

if (count($no_id) == count($new_array)) {
    // 2 arrays have same number of items => they are equal => no duplicates
    $redirect = "questionnair.php";
} else {
    // 2 arrays have different number of items => they are not equal => duplicates
    $redirect = "home.php";
}

header("location: {$redirect}");
```

**NOTE**
You have to redirect to an another PHP page (ex. home.php and not just home).

Comment: I not use type file on "home" or "questionnair", because using .htaccess. but thanks for helping. I can get a new way about arrays. thank you @Giacomo

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach (array_unique($no_id) as $key => $value)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_count_values` for this, not tested, but could be like:

```php
$counts = array_count_values($no_id);

$duplicate = false;
foreach ($no_id as $value) {
    if ($counts[$value] > 1) {
       $duplicate = true;
       break; // found a duplicate, no need to check further.
    }
}

if ($duplicate === true) {
    header('location:../../home');
} else {
    header('location:../../questionnair');
}
```

Comment: thank you, your code is work. I have question. are code "$ count" on $counts = array_count_values($no_id); and "$count" on if ($counts[$value] > 1) { connected?

Comment: `$counts` builds an array of all values from `$no_id` as `['100100' =>2, '100200' =>2, ...]`. The foreach loops, loops through `$no_id`. First value from `$no_id` is '100100', which has a value of 2 in `$counts`, so it sets duplicate to true.

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)()

```
$no_id = array('100100','100200','100300','100200','100200','100100');
$no_id_unique = array_flip($no_id);

if(count($no_id) === count($no_id_unique)){
    header('location:../../questionnair');
}else{
    header('location:../../home');
}
exit();
```